# checkbox in groups?

Tags: php, jquery

i need to make "groups" or something with my checkboxes. i want to click on a checkbox and only those checkboxes are active which available then. Like in the car configuration. If you buy the electric mirror you cant chose the manual one.In my case i have Product 1A 1B 1C and 2A 2B 2C and if i chose product one i can only choose product 1A,1B,1C.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="">1A</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="">1B</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="">1C</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="">2A</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="">2B</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="">2C</label>
```

Comment: how i can do that, im not into this stuff :/. How do i deactive the Product 2 if i chose one of the Product 1

Comment: Then hide the remaining group

Comment: Do you really want to use checkboxes? Can't you use a dropdown whose values will depend on the chosen product?

Comment: I think he wants that once he's choosing product one, only 1A->1C can be checked. 2A->2C become kind of read only.

Comment: vicrabb is right! This is what i want. so i cant use radio buttons because there i can only choose one.

Comment: But there is something where you can choose product one first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class='product' value=""/>1A
<input type="checkbox" class='product' value=""/>1B
<input type="checkbox" class='product' value=""/>1C
<input type="checkbox" class='product' value=""/>2A
<input type="checkbox" class='product' value=""/>2B
<input type="checkbox"class='product'  value=""/>2C
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
 var $product = $('input.product');
$product.click(function() {
    $product.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});

})
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GBGRJ/)**

### *Added after comment from OP*

**This is the code after the comment that *if i chose 1A, i can also click on 1B and 1C but not on 2A,2B,2C****

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class='one' value=""/>1A
<input type="checkbox" class='one' value=""/>1B
<input type="checkbox" class='one' value=""/>1C<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class='two' value=""/>2A
<input type="checkbox" class='two' value=""/>2B
<input type="checkbox" class='two'  value=""/>2C
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
 var $one= $('input.one');
$one.click(function() {
    $one.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    if($one.filter(':checked').length>0) {
       $two.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else {
        $two.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

var $two= $('input.two');
$two.click(function() {
    $two.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
    if($two.filter(':checked').length>0) {
       $one.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else {
        $one.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBGRJ/3/)

Comment: not exactly, if i chose 1A, i can also click on 1B and 1C but not on 2A,2B,2C.

Comment: we are getting close, but i only can click one prodcut of product 2 (or 1) it should be possible to click 2A,2B,2C at the same time. Aaaand is there any way to do this dynamiclly? i dont know how many product groups are coming...and with this way i have to add many jquery code ^^

Comment: yes like this! Any idea do this with more  productgroups without creating a function for every group?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look at [radio button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/radio) types rather

Answer (score 0):

If you are using checkboxes, you should address them as an array in your PHP code as well as giving them a `name` attribute (which is how PHP sees them):

```
<input type="checkbox" name ="checkbox1" value="">1A</label>
```

In your PHP code:

```
$checkArray=$_REQUEST['checkbox1'];
foreach($checkArray as $val)
{
    echo $val;// Value is echo'ed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="checkbox" class='group1' value=""/>1A

<input type="checkbox" class='group1' value=""/>1B

<input type="checkbox" class='group1' value=""/>1C

<input type="checkbox" class='group2' value=""/>2A

<input type="checkbox" class='group2' value=""/>2B

<input type="checkbox" class='group2'  value=""/>2C

<br/>
```

jquery

```
<br />
    <script>
    $(function(){
      var $product=$('input:checkbox');
      $product.click(function() {
        $product.attr('checked',false);
        var classname=$(this).attr('class');
        $('.'+classname).attr('checked','checked');
      });    
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: looks nice, but it has to be possible to check only one or two. not everytime all three :(

Comment: one or two.. i am not getting you... :)

Comment: so if i check say 1A .. which one should be checked.. in my case it checks all three... 1A,1B,1C.... if u want to check only two out of this ... thn atleast i think ,u shuld knw which two shuld be checked first..